# Doctrine one-to-many performance at scale

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've built a news feed with `post` having a one-to-many relationship with `post_reaction`. The concept is simple, a post can be liked, and each like is stored in the `post_reaction` table alongside with who liked it and the type of reaction (like, love, etc.)

Everything works just fine™, however as things scale, performance decreases, namely as the `post_reaction` table grows.

For testing purposes, I generated 200 posts and gave each post 1,000 reactions. This results in 200,000 total reactions stored in the `post_reaction` table.

My Twig template is provided a list of posts, limited to 20. As the template iterates through displaying each post, it then calls `post.reactions|length` to count the number of reactions. This executes the following db query:

```sql
SELECT
  t0.reaction AS reaction_1,
  t0.id AS id_2,
  t0.created AS created_3,
  t0.post_id AS post_id_4,
  t0.user AS user_5
FROM
  post_reaction t0
WHERE
  t0.post_id = ?
```

This query takes on average 4-7ms to run each time it runs for the 20 posts I'm rendering. This totals to ~100ms worth of DB queries just to count the posts.

That doesn't seem too bad, however we observe some overhead processing this much data in the application.

Taking a look at the profiler for the entire request, we see the following:
[image: Page performance profile]
Our overall processing time in this request was **585ms**

`components/news_post.html.twig` is the component that calls `post.reactions|length` which triggers the db query. If we initiate the same request without querying reactions, we observe the following.
[image: Page performance profile - without querying reactions]
Our overall processing time in this request was **179ms**

**406ms/69.4% faster**. I believe this is mostly attributed by overhead in doctrine while it processes the 20,000 rows into objects, only for us to count them later.

In an attempt to mitigate this, I wanted to see if joining the reactions onto my post query would help.

```sql
SELECT
  p0_.replies_allowed AS replies_allowed_0,
  p0_.highlight_date AS highlight_date_1,
  p0_.title AS title_2,
  p0_.content AS content_3,
  p0_.id AS id_4,
  p0_.created AS created_5,
  p0_.updated AS updated_6,
  p0_.news_feed_id AS news_feed_id_7,
  p0_.created_by_id AS created_by_id_8,
  p0_.updated_by_id AS updated_by_id_9
FROM
  post p0_
  INNER JOIN post_reaction p1_ ON (p1_.post_id = p0_.id)
WHERE
  p0_.news_feed_id = ?
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN p0_.highlight_date > ? THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
  p0_.created DESC
LIMIT
  20
```

However it causes issues with the `LIMIT 20` clause in the query, as joining reactions only allows one post to return due to the number of reactions in this dataset.

I'm not sure if I should continue to develop a way to make joining possible, or explore an alternative, whatever that may be. Ideally I'd like to reduce the 406ms of extra execution time since it's almost 70% of the total page processing time, just to count likes..

---

Edit: As requested, the output for `show create table post_reaction`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `post_reaction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reaction` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reaction_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_1B3A8E564B89032C` (`post_id`),
  KEY `IDX_1B3A8E568D93D649` (`user`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1B3A8E564B89032C` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1B3A8E568D93D649` FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200786 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: your query joining post and post_reaction needs to `group by p0_.id`; then you will get one row per post and can do some kind of count or sum or sums on post_reaction columns to get whatever summary data you want for each post

Comment: @ysth that gets me halfway there! I can count all the reactions, but the curveball is that `post_reaction` has a column `reaction` and I need to count all the distinct values by that column. It's so that I can count likes, laughs and all that separately. It's basically an int for use as an enum. I can't figure out an easy way to incorporate that into the query, especially when limiting the results

Comment: Assuming you can hardcore all the possible values of reaction, this is `select ..., sum(case when reaction=likevalue then 1 end) likes, sum(case when reaction=laughvalue then 1 end) laughs,...`

Comment: If you can't hardcore, search for pivot queries in mysql

Answer (score 0):

- (2nd query)  Don't `JOIN` to `post_reaction` since you are not using any columns from it.
- The complexity of the `ORDER BY` makes it impossible to do anything faster look at all 1000 reactions.  Hence the `LIMIT` has very little effect on performance.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE post_reaction`, there may be some improvements we can make there.  But you certainly need some index *starting* with `post_id`.  We may get some improvement by rearranging the `PRIMARY KEY` to start with that column.
- (I don't know anything about the Controller or twigs.  *They* seem to be the costly part?)

**More**

"count the number of reactions [for every post]" -- That is a single SQL query that won't take long:

```
SELECT post_id,
       COUNT(*) AS reaction_count
    FROM post_reaction
    GROUP BY post_id;
```

No iterating through posts; no 20 at a time; everything done in one simple pass over an index in that one table.

I tried an equivalent query on a table of 500K cities in 92 countries.  It took 0.13 seconds.

The lesson here is that SQL shines when it is asked to do lots of the same thing on lots of rows.

Comment: For the second query, yeah I was just experimenting with a join, and even if I select the output I don't have a way to make doctrine initialise the mapped property on the object with the extra values.
The limit is mainly for the `post` portion of the query. If I were to pull every post + all the reactions, I'd hit OOM errors on the application level trying to process that much data received from the db.
I've edited my post to include the create table sql.

Comment: And lastly with the controller/twig bit, they have the ability to call subsequent DB queries. This is why the twig is taking lots of time in the first example, because when it's trying to render each post, it's essentially calling `$post->getReactions()` which is uninitialised at the time and doctrine goes to fetch it; thus the profiler understands that this is time spent while rendering the twig template because that's where it's being called. I'm trying to limit going back to doctrine to ask for reactions every time I iterate through each post.

Comment: @SteppingHat - Check out what I added.  I conclude that Doctrine is holding you back.